# Adding a new column to a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column to a spark dataframe which has been registered as a table. This column needs to have an auto incrementing long.

```
df = spark.sql(query)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("user_stories")
df = spark.sql("ALTER TABLE user_stories ADD COLUMN rank int AUTO_INCREMENT")
df.show(5)
```

This throws the following error,

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE user_stories ADD COLUMN'(line 1, pos 29)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE user_stories ADD COLUMN rank int AUTO_INCREMENT
-----------------------------^^^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How's this question a duplicate, I need an auto increment value in the new column, I don't see that addressed in the question you've cited.

Comment: There is no auto increment in spark. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add new incremental column to DF, you could do in following ways.

```
df.show()
+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|gaurnag|
+-------+   
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
new_df = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
new_df.show()
+-------+---+
|   name| id|
+-------+---+
|gaurnag|  0|
+-------+---+
```